# WM_MOUSELEAVE and Parent-Child windows

Tags: c, winapi

In a main window `hwndFrame`, it has a child `hwndChild` which has a child `hwndDescendant`. These two childs have no non-client area. `hwndDescendant` occupy most of the region of `hwndChild`, so `hwndChild` looks like just a "boundry" of `hwndDescendant`. This "boundry" has width 4 pixels only. (But the size of `hwndChild` is much big than this).

I want to track `WM_MOUSELEAVE` for 'hwndChild'. If I move the mouse slowly, this works fine.
But if I move mouse very quickly from `hwndFrame` to `hwndDescendant` or vice versa, `hwndChild` didn't receive `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, hence neither `WM_MOUSELEAVE`.

Also when mouse move from `hwndChild` to either `hwndFrame` or `hwndDescendant` will generate WM_MOUSELEAVE. But I wish that when move from `hwndChild` to `hwndDescendant` don't generate `WM_MOUSELEAVE`.

I don't want to solve this issue by subclass the window procedure of `hwndDescendant`, because if `hwndChild` has many childs, it is not a good way.

`SetCapture` method is not preferable. In this case, what is the best way taht I can deal with this issue?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? See when the mouse moves into hwndFrame from any of the child windows?

Comment: Go easy on the backtick, it is just hard to read.

Comment: @Jonathan: I want to determine when the mouse is moved out from the rectangle of hwndChild to hwndFrame. But when mouse move over hwndDescendant, it is considered as not over hwndChild, so using WM_MOUSELEAVE for hwndChild doesn't work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I would forget about using WM_MOUSELEAVE and track this yourself with a simple flag and WM_MOUSEMOVE. When hwndChild gets a WM_MOUSEMOVE message set a flag to true, and when hwndFrame gets a WM_MOUSEMOVE message check the flag value - if it's set to true, you know the mouse has just come back from the child window.

Comment: @Jonathan: This looks like can get the effect: "moving from hwndChild to hwndDescendent is not a leaving from hwndChild". But the second issue still exists: "when moving very quickly from hwndDescendent to hwndFrame, no WM_MOUSEMOVE generated for hwndChild (Hence your suggestion don't work in this case)". I may set the flag to be true when mouse over hwndDescendent also and I think it works. But I want to know if there is a solution that I don't have to subclass hwndDescendent, otherwise it means that I have to subclass all childs if hwndChild has a lot of controls. thank you for a suggestion.